# Breaking the smithing cap?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-one

So, I’m level 46 with 100 smithing and enchanting. I want to make the best armor I possibly can, so I was wondering how to break the smithing cap with potions the best way that was intended. What I mean by this is I don’t want to exploit the system for smithing to be boosted to some ridiculous number like 1440%, rather, what is the best boost I can do to my armor and weapons while not feeling like a cheating as*wipe. I also understand alchemy will most likely be needed, so I’ll be sure to 100 that as well.

Comment: *"what is the best boost I can do to my armor and weapons while not feeling like a cheating as\*wipe"* That is pretty much entirely subjective.

Comment: I assume the main thing you're referring to is the "fortify alchemy enchant->fortfy enchantment potion" trick, in which case then my advice would be to follow the steps in the answers to the linked question but skip steps that have you stack these effects repeatedly.

Comment: The linked question has an answer that will tell you all about how to gain the highest amount of armor without cheating.

Answer (score 1):

I found this tidbit of information section of the trivia section of the fortify smithing page [HERE](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Fortify_Smithing).

> To achieve the maximum percent increase for Fortify Smithing Potions
>   of 194%, one must use four 39% enchanted armor pieces of Alchemy to
>   craft the potion. Then, for the actual smithing, one must then combine
>   this potion with four 39% enchanted armor pieces of smithing for
>   maximum smithing upgrades to items (using smithing-specific items
>   only).

So one potion of 194% fortify smiting, 4 armor pieces of 39% fortify smithing will give you the maximum fortification of fortify smithing, according to the article.

As a step further, you then need to increase the perk tree of the armor type you are using to 100 to increase damage reduction and put a few skills into the tree